# Remove space between plotted data and the axes

Tags: r, plot, ggplot2

I have the following dataframe:

```
uniq <- structure(list(year = c(1986L, 1987L, 1991L, 1992L, 1993L, 1994L, 1995L, 1996L, 1997L, 1998L, 1999L, 2000L, 2001L, 2002L, 2003L, 2004L, 2005L, 2006L, 2007L, 2008L, 2009L, 2010L, 2011L, 2012L, 2013L, 2014L, 1986L, 1987L, 1991L, 1992L, 1993L, 1994L, 1995L, 1996L, 1997L, 1998L, 1999L, 2000L, 2001L, 2002L, 2003L, 2004L, 2005L, 2006L, 2007L, 2008L, 2009L, 2010L, 2011L, 2012L, 2013L, 2014L, 1986L, 1987L, 1991L, 1992L, 1993L, 1994L, 1995L, 1996L, 1997L, 1998L, 1999L, 2000L, 2001L, 2002L, 2003L, 2004L, 2005L, 2006L, 2007L, 2008L, 2009L, 2010L, 2011L, 2012L, 2013L, 2014L), uniq.loc = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L), .Label = c("u.1", "u.2", "u.3"), class = "factor"), uniq.n = c(1, 1, 1, 2, 5, 4, 2, 16, 16, 10, 15, 14, 8, 12, 20, 11, 17, 30, 17, 21, 22, 19, 34, 44, 56, 11, 0, 0, 3, 3, 7, 17, 12, 21, 18, 10, 12, 9, 7, 11, 25, 14, 11, 17, 12, 24, 59, 17, 36, 50, 59, 12, 0, 0, 0, 1, 4, 6, 3, 3, 9, 3, 4, 2, 5, 2, 12, 6, 8, 8, 3, 2, 9, 5, 20, 7, 10, 8), uniq.p = c(100, 100, 25, 33.3, 31.2, 14.8, 11.8, 40, 37.2, 43.5, 48.4, 56, 40, 48, 35.1, 35.5, 47.2, 54.5, 53.1, 44.7, 24.4, 46.3, 37.8, 43.6, 44.8, 35.5, 0, 0, 75, 50, 43.8, 63, 70.6, 52.5, 41.9, 43.5, 38.7, 36, 35, 44, 43.9, 45.2, 30.6, 30.9, 37.5, 51.1, 65.6, 41.5, 40, 49.5, 47.2, 38.7, 0, 0, 0, 16.7, 25, 22.2, 17.6, 7.5, 20.9, 13, 12.9, 8, 25, 8, 21.1, 19.4, 22.2, 14.5, 9.4, 4.3, 10, 12.2, 22.2, 6.9, 8, 25.8)), .Names = c("year", "uniq.loc", "uniq.n", "uniq.p"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -78L))
```

When I make an area-plot with:

```
ggplot(data = uniq) + 
  geom_area(aes(x = year, y = uniq.p, fill = uniq.loc), stat = "identity", position = "stack") +
  scale_x_continuous(limits=c(1986,2014)) +
  scale_y_continuous(limits=c(0,101)) +
  theme_bw()
```

I get this result:

[image]

However, I want to remove the space between the axis and the actual plot. When I add `theme(panel.grid = element_blank(), panel.margin = unit(-0.8, "lines"))` I get the following error message:

> ```
> Error in theme(panel.grid = element_blank(), panel.margin = unit(-0.8,  : 
>   could not find function "unit"
> ```

Any suggestions on how to solve this problem?

Comment: I think you needed to explicitly load the grid package for `unit`

Comment: @TylerRinker Thanx! I don't get an error message anymore. I solved the problem already in another way, but this is a nice reminder for the future when I want to set margins.

Comment: This is sometimes referred to as a tight layout. Mentioning this here so that search engines can pick it up.

Answer (score 269, accepted):

**Update:** See [@divibisan's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52318834/2204410) for further possibilities in the latest versions of [ggplot2](/questions/tagged/ggplot2).

---

From `?scale_x_continuous` about the `expand`-argument:

> Vector of range expansion constants used to add some padding around
>   the data, to ensure that they are placed some distance away from the
>   axes. The defaults are to expand the scale by 5% on each side for
>   continuous variables, and by 0.6 units on each side for discrete
>   variables.

The problem is thus solved by adding `expand = c(0,0)` to `scale_x_continuous` and `scale_y_continuous`. This also removes the need for adding the `panel.margin` parameter.

The code:

```
ggplot(data = uniq) + 
  geom_area(aes(x = year, y = uniq.p, fill = uniq.loc), stat = "identity", position = "stack") +
  scale_x_continuous(limits = c(1986,2014), expand = c(0, 0)) +
  scale_y_continuous(limits = c(0,101), expand = c(0, 0)) +
  theme_bw() +
  theme(panel.grid = element_blank(),
        panel.border = element_blank())
```

The result:
[image: plot area chart with no gaps]

Answer (score 94):

As of [`ggplot2 version 3`](https://github.com/tidyverse/ggplot2/blob/master/NEWS.md#scales-and-guides), there is an `expand_scale()` function that you can pass to the `expand=` argument that lets you specify different expand values for each side of the scale.

As of [`ggplot2 version 3.3.0`](https://github.com/tidyverse/ggplot2/blob/master/NEWS.md#minor-improvements-and-bug-fixes), `expand_scale()` has been deprecated in favor of `expansion` which otherwise functions identically.

It also lets you choose whether you want to the expansion to be an absolute size (use the `add=` parameter) or a percentage of the size of the plot (use the `mult=` parameter):

```
ggplot(data = uniq) + 
  geom_area(aes(x = year, y = uniq.p, fill = uniq.loc), stat = "identity", position = "stack") +
  scale_x_continuous(limits = c(1986,2014), expand = c(0, 0)) +
  scale_y_continuous(limits = c(0,101), expand = expansion(mult = c(0, .1))) +
  theme_bw()
```

[image]

---

Since this is my top-voted answer, I thought I'd expand this to better illustrate the difference between `add=` and `mult=`.  Both options expand the plot area a specific amount outside the data. Using `add`, expands the area by a absolute amount (in the units used for that axis) while `mult` expands the area by a specified proportion of the total size of that axis.

In the below example, I expand the bottom using `add=10`, which extends the plot area by 10 units down to -10. I exapand the top using `mult=.15` which extends to top of the plot area by 15% of the total size of the data on the y-axis. Since the data goes from 0-100, that is 0.15 * 100 = 15 units – so it extends up to 115.

```
ggplot(data = uniq) + 
    geom_area(aes(x = year, y = uniq.p, fill = uniq.loc),
              stat = "identity", position = "stack") +
    scale_x_continuous(limits = c(1986,2014), expand = c(0, 0)) +
    scale_y_continuous(limits = c(0,101),
                       breaks = seq(-10, 115, by=15),
                       expand = expansion(mult = c(0, .15),
                                          add = c(10, 0))) +
    theme_bw()
```

[image]

Comment: Is there any way to remove the expansion from the theme? I would love to be able to have it be absent by default (perhaps it would need to be a custom `scale_*` function)

Comment: @MokeEire Not that I know of. I think your idea is the best: you could define a custom function which is the scale with this default setting. `sxc <- function(...) scale_x_continuous(expand = expansion(add=0), ...)`. Then you can use `sxc` as you'd use `scale_x_continuous`, even passing in other arguments, but with that default setting.

Answer (score 23):

Another option producing identical results, is using `coord_cartesian` instead of continuous position scales (x & y):

```
ggplot(data = uniq) +  
  geom_area(aes(x = year, y = uniq.p, fill = uniq.loc), stat = "identity", position = "stack") +  
  coord_cartesian(xlim = c(1986,2014), ylim = c(0,101))+
  theme_bw() + theme(panel.grid=element_blank(), panel.border=element_blank())
```

Comment: Nice alternative, +1. However, you will still need the `scales_x/y_continuous` parts if you want to specify the breaks ,etc.

Comment: or, even easier, set `expand = FALSE` in `coord_cartesian` as suggested in @Marcus [comment in this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/59079147/7941188)

Comment: @Tjebo The output is slightly different but in fact it is probably closer to the expected outcome by the OP. I will add it later to my answer. Thank you.