# Remove extra space beyond xlim and ylim

Tags: r, ggplot2

I'd like to make a density plot so that the axes are right next to (or at least very close to) the tick marks. As seen in this MWE, `ggplot2` reserved some space between the tick marks and the axes in both the x- and the y-axis, even when I have specified the `xlim` and `ylim`. How can I remove them?

With other kinds of plots, it seems like you can call something like `scale_y_continuous(limits=c(0, 100), expand = c(0, 0))` ([for example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22945651/how-to-remove-space-between-axis-area-plot-in-ggplot2)), but calling `scale_linetype_manual()` with these parameters doesn't seem to do anything.

Also note that in the note here I am drawing the axes using `geom_segment`. Is there a better way to do this?

```
set.seed(0)
the.df <- data.frame( x = rnorm(800, 50, 10), group = rep(letters[1:8], each = 100))

p <- ggplot(the.df) + 
    stat_density(aes(x = x, linetype = group), geom = "line", position = "identity") +
    xlim(10, 90) + ylim(0, 0.06) +
    scale_linetype_manual(values = c("11", "12", "13", "14", "21", "22", "23", "24")) +
    geom_segment(aes(x = 10, y = 0, xend = 90, yend = 0)) +
    geom_segment(aes(x = 10, y = 0, xend = 10, yend = 0.06))

p
```

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Turns out `scale_x_continuous()` and `scale_x_continuous` do work. I just didn't use them correctly.

```
set.seed(0)
the.df <- data.frame( x = rnorm(800, 50, 10), group = rep(letters[1:8], each = 100))

p <- ggplot(the.df) + 
    stat_density(aes(x = x, linetype = group), geom = "line", position = "identity") +
    scale_linetype_manual(values = c("11", "12", "13", "14", "21", "22", "23", "24")) +
    scale_x_continuous(limits=c(10, 90), expand = c(0, 0)) +
    scale_y_continuous(limits=c(0, 0.06), expand = c(0, 0)) +
    geom_segment(aes(x = 10, y = 0, xend = 90, yend = 0)) +
    geom_segment(aes(x = 10, y = 0, xend = 10, yend = 0.06))

p
```

Answer (score 7):

Another option using `coord_cartesian` instead of continuous position scales (x & y):

```
set.seed(0)
the.df <- data.frame( x = rnorm(800, 50, 10), group = rep(letters[1:8], each = 100))
p <- ggplot(the.df) + 
  stat_density(aes(x = x, linetype = group), geom = "line", position = "identity") +
  scale_linetype_manual(values = c("11", "12", "13", "14", "21", "22", "23", "24")) +
  geom_segment(aes(x = 10, y = 0, xend = 90, yend = 0)) +
  geom_segment(aes(x = 10, y = 0, xend = 10, yend = 0.06))+
  coord_cartesian(xlim = c(10, 90), ylim = c(0, .06), expand = FALSE)
p
```

[image]

Comment: Note that now you need to add expand = FALSE to coord_cartesian.

Comment: @machow Noted and changed it. I assume this behaviour has changed in one of the releases. Thank you.