# How can I set exactly the limits for axes in ggplot2 R plots?

Tags: r, plot, ggplot2

Making a plot with ggplot, I wish to set my axis **exactly**. I am aware that I can set the plot range (e.g. for the x-axis I specified limits from 2 to 4) with `coord_cartesian()` but that **leaves a bit of space to the left and right of the range I specify**:

[image]

Code for the MWE above:

```
library(ggplot2)

data.mwe = cbind.data.frame(x = 1:5, y = 2:6)

plot.mwe = ggplot(data = data.mwe, aes(x=x,y=y)) + geom_line() + coord_cartesian(xlim = c(2,4))
print(plot.mwe)
```

My desired result is a plot where the displayed area is exactly between the limits I specify.

I am aware of 
[How to set limits for axes in ggplot2 R plots?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3606697/4986317)
but it does not answer my question, as it produces the undesired result above, or cuts out observations (with the `limits` argument to `scale_x_continuous`). I know I could tinker with setting a smaller range for limits, but I am looking for a clean result. At the least I would like to know by how much the actual range differs from the one I specify, so that I could adapt my limits accordingly.

Comment: [This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23710875/remove-extra-space-beyond-xlim-and-ylim) is similar to the present question.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Add `expand = FALSE`:

```r
library(ggplot2)

data.mwe = data.frame(x = 1:5, 
                      y = 2:6)

ggplot(data.mwe, aes(x, y)) + 
    geom_line() + 
    coord_cartesian(xlim = c(2, 4), 
                    expand = FALSE)
```

[image]

Comment: Exactly what I needed! I know this is almost a new Q, but is there any feature to toggle the `expand = F` for only one of the two axis? In your example also the y-range is no longer expanded, what if I wanted it to be?

Comment: Use `scale_x_continuous` instead of `coord_cartesian`: `ggplot(data.mwe, aes(x, y)) + 
    geom_line() + scale_x_continuous(limits = c(2, 4), expand = c(0, 0))` Its `expand` parameter wants a length-2 vector of expansion constants for the two margins instead of a Boolean, but otherwise it works the same.

Comment: nice, thanks again! Unfortunately `scale_x_continuous` also drops observations outside of the range. Admittedly in my MWE that does not make a difference, but in some of my applications it does.

Comment: The only way I can think that it would make a difference is with a smooth, in which case you can build the model outside ggplot.