# ggplot manipulate axis margins

Tags: r, ggplot2, axis

I have a bar plot of categorical variables. I'm trying to make the labels for the axis flush with the axis; essentially, justify the base of the bars to the labels. Any help would be appreciated.

Here's the code for the graph.

```
travel_deaths %>%
     filter(Type %in% commuting,
                      data_type == "Journeys") %>% #filter out the stupid air travels
     mutate(rank = rank(.$deaths)) %>%
     ggplot(aes(x = reorder(Type, rank, order = TRUE), y = deaths, fill = factor(rank))) +
     geom_bar(stat="identity", show.legend = FALSE) +
     geom_text(aes(label = deaths), nudge_y = 40) +
     ggtitle("Deaths per Billion Trips") +
     scale_fill_manual(values = bloody(9)) +
     theme(axis.text.y = element_text(hjust = 1),
           axis.ticks.y = element_blank()) +
     coord_flip()
```

Currently it looks like this

[image: Currently image]

This is what I am hoping to achieve

[image: Hopeful image]

Comment: Does adding `scale_y_continuous(expand = c(0,0), limits = c(0, 1700))` before you flip the coordinates give you what you're looking for?

Comment: That did help! Can you explain what is happening in that line of code?

Comment: Duplicate of [How to remove space between axis & area-plot in ggplot2?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22945651/how-to-remove-space-between-axis-area-plot-in-ggplot2)

Comment: And duplicate of [How can I set exactly the limits for axes in ggplot2 R plots?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48255449/how-can-i-set-exactly-the-limits-for-axes-in-ggplot2-r-plots?noredirect=1&lq=1)