# How set the limits of the plotting area of a multiple line graph (ggplot) when x values are of type factor?

Tags: r, ggplot2

My graph looks like this:

[image: graph]

The code I use is this

```
graph_substrat <- ggplot(substrat_long, aes(x=substrat,y=value, 
+ group=variable, linetype=variable)) + geom_line() + ylab("Suitability Index") 
+ xlab("Substrat") + background_grid(major = "xy", minor = "none")

graph_substrat <- graph_substrat + theme(legend.position="none")
```

I only want to plot the line between *Cobble* and *Sand*, and delete the free space in the beginning and end of the graph, so that the lines start at the Y-axis (or at least very close to it, and ends with the the last tick on the X-axis).

I tried it with `limits`, `expand` and `coord_cartesian`, but it did not work.

Note that X is of type `factor` and not `numeric`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Include `expand = c(0,0)` in `scale_x_discrete` as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22945651/how-to-remove-space-between-axis-area-plot-in-ggplot2).

Compare this plot:

```
library(ggplot2)
ggplot(iris, aes(x = Species, y = Petal.Length)) +
  stat_summary(fun.y = "mean", geom = "bar")
```

[image]

To the one with `expand = c(0,0)`:

```
ggplot(iris, aes(x = Species, y = Petal.Length)) +
  stat_summary(fun.y = "mean", geom = "bar") +
  scale_x_discrete(expand = c(0,0))
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks! I had tried to solve it with `expand=c(0,0)` but I did it for the wrong aesthetics.   `scale_x_discrete (expand=c(0,0))` does the trick!