# Removing space between plot and axis as default in ggplot2?

Tags: r, ggplot2

I like the classic look theme in ggplot2:

```
library(ggplot2)
thm <- theme_classic() 
theme_set(thm)

set.seed(123)
a <- data.frame(var=rnorm(2000))
ggplot(a,aes(var)) + geom_histogram()
```

[image]

As per [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22945651/how-to-remove-space-between-axis-area-plot-in-ggplot2), I can remove the space between the data and the axes using `expand=c(0,0)` in the `scale_x_continuous` and `scale_y_continuous` options.

But is there a way I can set this as the default in `thm`?

Comment: If there is an answer to this I don't think it lies in the theming system, as that is generally separate from the scales and geoms that form the content of the plot.

Comment: Also be aware that would not necessarily be generally useful, as e.g. in a scatterplot points with the smallest x or y will get cut in half.

Comment: I agree with you that many graphs look better without the space, and with the axis starting at 0. Unfortunately, I don't think there is any way to make this a default or write it into a theme - I just include the `expand = c(0,0)` code in most plots I make.