# ggplot2 coord_flip remove space

Tags: r, ggplot2, bar-chart

When I use coord_flip in ggplo2 using this code

```
# rotate to make more readable
p1 <- ggplot(mtcars, aes(x = row.names(mtcars), mpg)) +
        geom_bar(stat = "identity") +
        coord_flip() +
        ggtitle("Fig. A: Default rotated x-axis")

# order bars
p2 <- ggplot(mtcars, aes(x = reorder(row.names(mtcars), mpg), y = mpg)) +
        geom_bar(stat = "identity") +
        coord_flip() +
        ggtitle("Fig. B: Rotated ordered x-axis")

grid.arrange(p1, p2, ncol = 2)
```

I get the following chart

[image]

I have highlighted the space that exists next to y axis,  PLease can you help me understand how I can remove that.

Comment: add `scale_y_continuous(expand = c(0, 0))` and this should be fixed.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22945651/how-to-remove-space-between-axis-area-plot-in-ggplot2