# In ggplot, how can I make a grid along x and y axis between categories?

Tags: r, ggplot2

Below is the reproducible R script for plot without any `panel.grid`

```
require(ggplot2)
library(ggrepel)
# Create the data frame.
sales_data <- data.frame(
  emp_name = rep(c("Sam", "Dave", "John", "Harry", "Clark", "Kent", "Kenneth", "Richard", "Clement", "Toby", "Jonathan"), times = 5), 
  month = as.factor(rep(c("Jan", "Feb", "Mar", "Jan", "Feb", "Mar", "Jan", "Feb", "Mar", "Jan", "Jan"), times = 5)),
  dept_name = as.factor(rep(c("Production", "Services", "Support", "Support", "Services", "Production", "Production", "Support", "Support", "Support", "Production"), times = 5)), 
  revenue = rep(c(100, 200, 300, 400, 500, 600, 500, 400, 300, 200, 500), times = 5)
)

sales_data$month <- factor(sales_data$month, levels = c("Jan", "Feb", "Mar"))
month_vector <- levels(sales_data$month)
number_of_enteries <- nrow(sales_data)

sales_data$month <- as.integer(sales_data$month)

ggplot(sales_data, aes(x = month, y = dept_name)) +
  geom_raster(data = expand.grid(sales_data$month, sales_data$dept_name), 
            aes(x = Var1, y = Var2, width=1, height=1), fill = NA, col = 'gray50', lty = 1) + #default width and height is 1
  geom_point(aes(size = revenue, col = revenue), 
             shape = 16, position = position_jitter(seed = 0), show.legend = F) +
  geom_text_repel(aes(label = revenue), size=4, vjust = 1.6, position = position_jitter(seed = 0)) + #try with geom_text
  
  theme_bw() +
  theme(
    axis.title = element_blank(),
    axis.ticks = element_blank(),
    plot.background = element_blank(), 
    axis.line = element_blank(), 
    panel.border = element_blank(), 
    panel.grid = element_blank(),
    #panel.grid.major.y = element_line(colour = "red"),
    #panel.grid.major.x = element_line(colour = "red"),
    axis.text = element_text(colour = "blue", face = "plain", size =11)
  ) +
 
  scale_x_continuous(limits=c(0.5,3.5), expand = c(0,0), breaks = 1:length(month_vector), labels = month_vector)
```

**Output plot is**:
[image]
**Expected plot**:
[image]
I want to have tick lines along the x and y axis like shown in red line. I tried using `panel.grid` in `theme` but because of my custom added `scale_x_continuous` it is giving me unwanted major minor axes. Please uncomment line `panel.grid.major.y = element_line(colour = "red"),`to see the `major` grid.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Surprisingly, to the best of my knowledge, there doesn't seem to be a good way to get `panel.grid` lines between discrete categories. One way to get around this is to use `hline` and `vline` to add these lines:

To your `ggplot` code, add the following 3 lines:

```
# Remove extra whitespace from y-axis so lines are against the axis
scale_y_discrete(expand = c(0,0)) +
# Add straight lines at each factor level, shifted left/down so they're between values
geom_hline(yintercept = as.numeric(sales_data$dept_name) - 0.5) +
geom_vline(xintercept = as.numeric(sales_data$month) - 0.5)
```

[image: Plot with grid lines added]

Comment: Thank you ver much @divibisan.
One question. What exactly do you mean by `# Remove extra whitespace from y-axis so lines are against the axis`

Comment: By default, ggplot extends the plot a bit around the edges. So if you have a plot with  `xlim(c(0, 10))`, the left edge of the plot will actually be at -0.1 (or something like that). It normally makes it look nicer, but if you don't get rid of it here, you'll see that the vertical lines stick down past the lowest horizontal line

Comment: @OmPrakashSao You can see a good example on this question which deals with getting rid of that space: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22945651/how-to-remove-space-between-axis-area-plot-in-ggplot2/52318834#52318834