# Reduce left/right margins of ggplot2 panel

Tags: r, ggplot2, plot

Looking around in the ggplot2 documentation, I couldn't find a method to reduce the left and right margin in the plot panel itself.

I have this plot and would like the side areas of [this plot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5nAgH.png) (in the red boxes) to be as slim as the top and bottom margins. Which element of the plot to I have to modify and how? Thanks in advance! [Unfortunately not yet enough reputation to post inline images]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's hard to solve it for your case, as you haven't provided a [reproducible example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IUlvR.png), or the code you used to generate the plot, but you can add in `expand = c(0, 0)` to to the `scale_x_discrete` argument. `expand` controls the amount of padding around the axes, so setting it to the range zero fits the plot right next to the edge of the figure.

```
mtcars %>% 
    ggplot(aes(x=as.factor(carb), y=wt, fill=gear)) + 
    geom_bar(stat='identity', position='stack') + 
    scale_x_discrete(expand = c(0, 0)) +
    theme(legend.position = "none")
```

[image]

Comment: Yes, sorry. The code is a bit of a mess as all the gaps between samples are manually added to a `scale_x_continuous()` argument. But `expand()` worked! Thanks a bunch :)

Answer (score 0):

It would be useful if you could post with a reproducible example, but you can try using

```
scale_x_continuous(expand = c(0, 0))
```

like they have used in this other post:

[How to remove space between axis & area-plot in ggplot2?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22945651/how-to-remove-space-between-axis-area-plot-in-ggplot2)