# How to increase the space between the panel border and radial plot (ggplot2)

Tags: r, ggplot2, graphing, polar-coordinates

I'm having trouble getting the axis labels to fit properly on my facetted radial plots. I can't really

I use the coord_radar function to create straight lines around the radial plot:

```
  function(theta='x', start=0, direction=1){
    # input parameter sanity check
    match.arg(theta, c('x','y'))

    ggproto(
      NULL, CoordPolar, 
      theta=theta, r=ifelse(theta=='x','y','x'),
      start=start, direction=sign(direction),
      is_linear=function() TRUE)
  }
```

Then here's my graph:

```
ggplot(VGR.mpre, aes(y=value, x=variable.2, group=factor(X), colour=Impaired.Task.Score))+
  geom_polygon(fill = NA)+
  geom_path(aes(group=factor(X)))+
  geom_point()+
  coord_radar()+
  labs(x="Parameters", y="Z-score", title="Pre-op parameters for Visually Guided Reaching Task")+
  scale_colour_manual(name="Impaired (Task Score > 1.96)", labels=c("No", "Yes"), values=c("#619CFF", "#F8766D"))+
  theme(axis.text.x = element_text(face = VGR.mpre$face))+
  facet_wrap(.~factor(X), nrow=2)+
  theme_bw(base_size=25)+
  theme(legend.position="bottom", legend.box="horizontal")
```

When I export the image, some of the axis labels are always cut off. [This is a screenshot of the graph](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IOCnG.png). "No Movement end" for example is cut off.
I've tried using white space \n for the labels which worked for some of them, but I'm really wondering if there's a function that adjusts the amount of space between the panel borders and the graph itself. I can't seem to find the answer anywhere else on stack overflow, but if someone could link me to a similar question and/or help me out that would be super appreciated!!

Comment: check out https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22945651/how-to-remove-space-between-axis-area-plot-in-ggplot2 and "Related" tab on the side.

Comment: @Dylan_Gomes Thanks! I noticed a few of those related posts. I'm wondering which one you are referring to? And is there anything of note for radial plots?

Comment: Because the vjust and hjust don't seem to work for radial plots. I've tried the margins, but I don't see them making any difference in radial plots either :/