# How do you completely remove the spaces between facet strips (to connect a geom_rect 'background')?

Tags: r, ggplot2

I would like to create a plot in `R` with `ggplot2` in which there are figure backgrounds using `geom_rect` and also facetting to create nice labels (I think facet strips can be clearer than x-axis labels).

The issue I'm encountering is connecting the facet boxes together to remove any space between them. I tried to use `theme(panel.spacing = unit(0 , 'lines')` however this doesn't completely remove the space between facet panels.

```
require(ggplot2)

#Create a numeric Species variable for positioning the geom_rect objects.
iris$Species_num <- as.integer(iris$Species)

p <- ggplot(iris,
       aes(x = Species_num,
           fill = Species,
           y = Sepal.Length)
) + 
#Use geom_rect to add a coloured background to each Species' boxplot.
  geom_rect(
    aes(
      xmin = Species_num - .5,
      xmax = Species_num + .5,
      ymin = -Inf,
      ymax = Inf,
      fill = Species
    ),
    alpha = .01
  ) +
geom_boxplot() +
  facet_grid(~Species,
             scales = 'free') +
#Replace the numeric x axis labels with the original Species labels.
  scale_x_continuous(
    breaks = unique(iris$Species_num),
    labels = unique(iris$Species)
  )

p + theme(
    panel.spacing = unit(0,'lines')
  )
```

[image: Iris boxplot plot facetted by Species, in which there is a small grey space between panels (the bits not covered by geom_rect).]

Using negative values here causes the panels to infringe on the panel to its respective right-hand neighbouring panel, still with space between them.

```
p + theme(
  panel.spacing = unit(-4,'lines')
)
```

[image: Iris boxplot plot facetted by Species, in which the right-hand panels are encroaching on their left neighbours.]

Versions:

```
ggplot2_3.3.2
R version 4.0.2 (2020-06-22)
Platform: x86_64-apple-darwin17.0 (64-bit)
Running under: macOS Mojave 10.14.6
```

Thanks in advance for the help!

Answer (score 3):

I think I may have just found the answer to this from:
[How to remove space between axis & area-plot in ggplot2?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22945651/how-to-remove-space-between-axis-area-plot-in-ggplot2?rq=1)

The problem is the space between the plot and the axes. One can remove this by putting `expand = c(0,0)` in the `scale_x_continuous` bit.

```
p <- ggplot(iris,
       aes(x = Species_num,
           fill = Species,
           y = Sepal.Length)
) + 
  geom_rect(
    aes(
      xmin = Species_num - .5,
      xmax = Species_num + .5,
      ymin = -Inf,
      ymax = Inf,
      fill = Species
    ),
    alpha = .01
  ) +
geom_boxplot() +
  facet_grid(~Species,
             scales = 'free') +
  scale_x_continuous(
    breaks = unique(iris$Species_num),
    labels = unique(iris$Species),
    expand = c(0,0)
  )

p + theme(
    panel.spacing = unit(0,'lines')
  )
```

[image]

Comment: I was 30 seconds away from posting that as an answer. Yes, I think this is the canonical/preferred way to do what you asked for.

Comment: It's always the way that one gets the answer when saying the question! This time it took me about five minutes from posting the question. Thanks for coming to answer nonethelss!!

Comment: I've written dozens of questions where, while fashioning a min-reprex, I found the culprit and solved it before hitting "Post".