# Reducing panel height/width in a ggplot & cropping the white space in R Markdown

Tags: r, ggplot2, graph

Please don't close this and tell me the answer is on [Remove space between plotted data and the axes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22945651/remove-space-between-plotted-data-and-the-axes) because that is not the same plot and does not work here. Using expand makes the bar large.

My original issue was too much panel which is detailed below and I solved using

```
library(patchwork)
plot11f + plot_layout(ncol = 1,nrow =5)
```

I was able to get the nice skinny plot with less grey, but when in my markdown document it has a big white space under it. Using plot.margins doesn't help, it chops off my axis labels and still gives the big white space.

[image]

--- Original question ---
I have produced the following ggplot (code and dummy data below) but I want to reduce the height of the grey panel bits (where I have scribbled in red) to make the graph shorter (I might even shrink the width of the bar further but need to know how to reduce the grey background panel first).

```
tableq11f<-data.frame(Q11f<-c("A","B","C","D","E"), percent<-c(0.03,0.07,0.22,0.46,0.22))
plot11f<-ggplot(data=tableq11, aes(x=percent, y="Q11", fill=Q11f))+
  geom_col(position = "fill", show.legend = FALSE, width=0.5)+ 
  scale_fill_brewer(palette="Blues")+theme(axis.title.x=element_blank(),
  axis.title.y=element_blank(),axis.text.y=element_blank(),axis.ticks.y=element_blank())+ 
  scale_x_continuous(labels = scales::percent)
```

[image: ggplot to alter]

More like this

[image: better image]

Comment: Does changing any [plot chunk options](https://yihui.org/knitr/options/#plots) change the output in the document? Like the figure size options or any of the `out.` options.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The empty space is there because you used patchwork to create a grid of your plot and four empty rows which isn't a suitable way to achieve your goal.  Instead, reduce the space between the bar and plot margins using `scale_y_discrete(expand = expansion(mult = .075))` and decrease the width of the bar in `geom_col()`, and finally as mentioned in the comments, set an appropriate figure size for the plot in the markdown chunk options.

````
---
title: "Untitled"
output: word_document
---

```{r, echo=FALSE, fig.width=5, fig.asp = .15}

library(ggplot2)

tableq11f<-data.frame(Q11f=c("A","B","C","D","E"), percent=c(0.03,0.07,0.22,0.46,0.22))

ggplot(data = tableq11f, aes(x = percent, y = "Q11", fill = Q11f)) +
  geom_col(position = "fill",
           show.legend = FALSE,
           width = 0.1) +
  scale_fill_brewer(palette = "Blues") +
  theme(
    axis.title.x = element_blank(),
    axis.title.y = element_blank(),
    axis.text.y = element_blank(),
    axis.ticks.y = element_blank()
  ) +
  scale_x_continuous(labels = scales::percent) +
  scale_y_discrete(expand = expansion(mult = .075))
    
```
````

Which gives:

[image]