# How to increase space between axis line and bars in a bar plot using ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2, bar-chart, axis, spacing

How could I increase the space between the y-axis line and the first bar in the following bar plot?

```
# Load ggplot
library(ggplot2)

# Load the Titanic dataset
data("Titanic")
Titanic <- as.data.frame(Titanic)

# Bar plot
ggplot(Titanic, aes(x = Class, y = Freq, fill = Survived)) + 
  geom_col(position = "fill") +
  coord_cartesian(ylim = c(0, 1), expand = FALSE) +
  theme_classic() +
  theme(legend.position = "none",
        axis.line.x = element_blank(),
        axis.ticks.x = element_blank())
```

Is there a way to apply `coord_cartesian(expand = FALSE)` only to the x-axis? This could resolve the problem.

[image]

Comment: Pretty sure this is a dupe of https://stackoverflow.com/q/22945651/5325862

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think you can get that level of control with `coord_cartesion`. You can use the scales instead

```
ggplot(Titanic, aes(x = Class, y = Freq, fill = Survived)) + 
  geom_col(position = "fill") +
  scale_x_discrete(expand=expansion(add=c(.8, 0))) + 
  scale_y_continuous(expand=expansion(add=c(0, 0))) + 
  theme_classic() +
  theme(legend.position = "none",
        axis.line.x = element_blank(),
        axis.ticks.x = element_blank())
```

Change the value of .8 to whatever you like.

[image]