# How do I force the origin to start at 0 for a gglot2 histogram

Tags: r, histogram

I mistakenly asked a question in the Discussions area that some folks nicely answered for me. The discussion was subsequently hidden by one of the moderators so I am reposting the question again here in case someone needs an answer to the same question in the future.

I am using the following code to create a histogram. The program almost works:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sftYG.png)

but I would like to set the origin for the y axis to 0 such that gap between the bottom of the bars and the x-axis is eliminated. Also I set color=black in the histogram statement in an attempt to set the outline of the bars to black and that work although now there is an additional black line at the zero line. My question is how to eliminate the gap and keep the black bar outlines without the second black line. Thanks in advance for any answers.

```
library(ggplot2)
ggplot(data=sifdat,mapping= aes(x=diff, fill=fdate)) +
  geom_histogram(binwidth=0.01,color="black", position = "dodge") +
scale_fill_manual(values=c("red","blue")) +
  theme(legend.position = c(15, .15), #<-Add Legend to upper right inside
        # Hide panel borders, remove grid lines, white background
        panel.border = element_blank(),
        panel.grid.major = element_blank(),
        panel.grid.minor = element_blank(),
        panel.background = element_blank(),
        axis.line = element_line(colour = "black"))
```

A fellow user RKeithL provided a link to code that provided a solution to the problem which is this location:

[Remove space between plotted data and the axes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22945651/remove-space-between-plotted-data-and-the-axes)

My thanks to RKeithL and to everyone else who tried to help.

Comment: Your question was probably closed as a duplicate as the post you referenced already contains the answer, e.g. `+ scale_y_continuous(expand = expansion(mult = c(0, .05)))` will remove the default expansion of the y scale at the lower end while keeping it at the upper end. The black zero line simply reflects the outline of bins with zero counts. But that should not be a big issue when you remove the expansion.

Comment: I don't really understand why duplicate posts as you call them are closed because you have  provided information in your answer that wasn't necessarily in the post RKeithL provided, It helps the user understand what the heck is going on with the code so thanks for your input.

Comment: When a question is closed as a dup this is not meant bad and dups are not bad at all. Actually they help others to find the "right" answers. But in short: The idea is to collect all answers and infos in one place. For a more lengthy discussion see [Why are some questions marked as duplicate?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/duplicates#:~:text=The%20fundamental%20goal%20of%20closing,those%20answers%20in%20one%20place.)

Comment: stephan  ok sorry i misunderstood ...thought this would eventually be deleted, Thanks!