# ggplot - full plot area

Tags: r, graphics, plot, ggplot2

I would like to save a plot, without any whitespace around the plot area.

[image: Example of Problem]

I have tried this code, but still have whitespace to left of yaxis, and below xaxis.

```
library(ggplot2)
    ggplot(data.frame(x=c(1,1,2,2),y=c(1,2,2,1)), aes(x, y)) +
    geom_polygon(fill="grey75") +
    geom_point(size=50,colour="yellow") +
    theme( 
    legend.position = "none",
    panel.background = element_blank(),
    panel.grid.major = element_blank(),
    panel.grid.minor = element_blank(),
    panel.margin = unit(0,"null"),
    plot.margin = rep(unit(0,"null"),4),
    axis.ticks = element_blank(),
    axis.text.x = element_blank(),
    axis.text.y = element_blank(),
    axis.title.x = element_blank(),
    axis.title.y = element_blank(),
    axis.ticks.length = unit(0,"null"),
    axis.ticks.margin = unit(0,"null"))+
    scale_x_continuous(expand=c(0,0)) + 
    scale_y_continuous(expand=c(0,0))][1]][1]
```

Comment: how are you saving the plot?

Comment: requires: labs(x=NULL, y=NULL)
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17786197/plot-margins-in-ggplot2