# How to remove margins in ggplot2 chart

Tags: r, pdf, ggplot2, visualization

I am currently creating plots with ggplot2 for a latex document and discovered that ggplot2 adds many unwanted margins:

[image]

- painted red by `plot.background=element_rect(fill="red")`:

  - small margin on the left
  - small margin between image and legend
- painted violet with photoshop:

  - margin on the left and the right
  - 1px margin on the bottom

---

Which more rules are needed to remove these margins? It's really difficult to google all these configuration options. This is my actual chart:

```
library(ggplot2)
library(scales)
label <- c("A", "B", "C", "D")
value <- c(61, 26, 9, 4)
values <- data.frame(label, value)
myplot <- ggplot(values, aes(x = "", y=value, fill=label))
myplot <- myplot + theme(legend.position="bottom")
myplot <- myplot + labs(fill="")
myplot <- myplot + geom_bar(stat="identity", width=1)
myplot <- myplot + geom_text(
  aes(x=1.3, y=value/2+c(0, cumsum(value)[-length(value)])),
  label=percent(value/100),
  size=2
)
myplot <- myplot + coord_polar(theta="y")
myplot <- myplot + theme(plot.background=element_rect(fill="red"))
myplot <- myplot + theme(
  plot.margin=unit(c(0,0,0,0), "mm"),
  legend.margin=unit(0, "mm"),
  axis.title=element_blank(),
  axis.ticks=element_blank()
)
ggsave("pie.pdf")
```

Comment: Dupe? [Remove plot margins in `ggplot2`](http://stackoverflow.com/a/17791455/903061) says `labs(x=NULL, y=NULL)` is also needed.

Comment: However it doesn't really seem to help, at least not with the red colored area.

Comment: why dont you just remove ``myplot <- myplot + theme(plot.background=element_rect(fill="red"))`` ?

Comment: Seems like you need to set `axis.text`, `axis.ticks.length`, and possibly `legend.box.spacing`.  That last one might be new in the development version of ggplot2.

Comment: @aosmith `axis.text` and `axis.ticks.length` have been the correct settings. Can you post this again as an answer that i can mark you answer the correct one?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can remove the rest of the axis space via the theme elements `axis.text` and `axis.tick.length`.

So you'd add something like the following to your `theme` code:

```
axis.text = element_blank(), axis.ticks.length = unit(0, "mm")
```

In the current development version of ggplot2, *ggplot2_2.1.0.9001*, there is a new theme element `legend.box.spacing` that could also be useful here to remove all space between the legend and the plot: `legend.box.spacing = unit(0, "mm")`.

Comment: `axis.text` and `axis.ticks.length` solved the problem

Answer (score 3):

Adjust the `plot.margin` settings so that the bottom and left side are negative numbers.

`plot.margin=unit(c(0,0,-12,-5), "mm")`

If you do get rid of the margin on the bottom, you are also sacrificing the legend.

Comment: The problem with this hardcoded values is that you have to recalculate them for every new chart type you make. If you know the correct margin and length options they will fit for every future possible chart you make.